# Error: no applicable method for 'bbox' applied to an object of Class "Extent"

Tags: qmap, extent

I am plotting how collared animals utilise water points using the recurse package, and working through the code supplied here, with my data replacing Leo's data: http://dx.doi.org/10.5441/001/1.46ft1k05 
I'm currently trying to map movement based on most frequently visited locations. However I keep getting an error in UseMethod "bbox".

When I use show(leoGeo),  it returns as a Move object, and I have enabled and registered a Google API key. I have recurse, move, ggplot2, ggmap, RgoogleMaps, raster, scales, viridis, lubridate, reshape2, raster, rworldmap, aptools, cluster, amt, sp, rgdal,curl and dplyr loaded.

```
leovisit50 = getRecursions(leo.df, 50)  
revisitThreshold = 75
leoGeo.map.df = as(leoGeo,'data.frame')
leoGeo.map.df$revisits = leovisit50$revisits
```

and when I go to use this command

```
map.leoGeo = qmap(bbox(extent(leoGeo[leovisit50$revisits > 
revisitThreshold,])), zoom = 13, maptype = "road.Dist")
```

it keeps returning the error below

```
Error in UseMethod("bbox", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'bbox' applied to an object of class "Extent"
```

(I can provide full code for this if that is required, it was just the map.leoGeo line I was having difficulty with).

I'm new to movement analysis and am not sure how to fix this problem,any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The method clearly exists

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()
e <- extent(r)
#bbox(e)
#    min max
#s1 -180 180
#s2  -90  90
```

So probably you are loading a package that hides that method. As you are not calling the method directly, you cannot do `raster::bbox`. Start with a fresh R session, and see if there are warnings that tell you about this when you load your packages. Try to avoid loading many packages, and avoid those that hide methods in other packages.